# Changing order of integration for Double Integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> How can i Changing order of integration for $$\int^{10}_{1}\int^{\ln(x)}_{0}g(x,y)dydx$$

What i try::

[image]

Changing order of integration, we get

$$\int^{\ln(x)}_{0}\int^{10}_{1}g(x,y)dxdy$$

Can anyone please tell me is i am Right or not.

If not, Then how do i change order of Integration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order of integration is based on equality of sets
$$  \left\{ \begin{array}{} 
1 \leqslant x \leqslant 10 \\
0 \leqslant y \leqslant \ln (x)
\end{array} \right\} = \left\{ \begin{array}{} 
0 \leqslant y \leqslant \ln(10) \\
e^y \leqslant x \leqslant 10
\end{array} \right\}$$
So integration will be
$$\int\limits^{10}_{1}\int\limits^{\ln(x)}_{0}g(x,y)dxdy = \int\limits^{\ln (10)}_{0}\int\limits^{10}_{e^y}g(x,y)dxdy$$

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct.

$\int_1^{10}\int_0^{\ln x } g(x,y)dydx=\int_0^{\ln (10)}\int_{e^{y}}^{10}g(x,y) dx dy$.  Note that the conditions $1<x<10, 0<y<\ln x$ are equivalent to the conditions $0<y<\ln (10), e^{y} <x<10$.